# How to replicate a FIFO queue with DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT and barrier blocks?

Tags: iphone, ios, concurrency, grand-central-dispatch

I read that `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` is a FIFO queue and will only run on one processor core.

My app fetches images from disk, applies effect, creates a UIImage and adds the image to an array. The order in the array must be the same as the order at which I read the images from disk.

When I use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` the order is maintained.

But what is the design pattern to use `DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT` so images get processed on all cores, but once processing is done they get added to array in FIFO order?

Documentation sais:

> A dispatch queue that executes blocks concurrently. Although they
>   execute blocks concurrently, you can use barrier blocks to create
>   synchronization points within the queue.

Is there example for barrier blocks to create a FIFO queue with concurrent processing?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to keep track of what index they should go in the array? Then no matter the order they finish being loaded, they will go at that index.

Comment: Yes I thought of this too. But I was hoping there is a GCD design pattern to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest GCD approach I can think of would be like this:

```
NSArray* arrayOfImages = <your array of images to be processed>;
NSMutableArray* processedImages = [arrayOfImages mutableCopy];
dispatch_queue_t protectMutableArray = dispatch_queue_create("", 0);
dispatch_apply(arrayOfImages.count, dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^(size_t index) {
    UIImage* unprocessedImage = arrayOfImages[index];
    UIImage* processedImage = ProcessImage(unprocessedImage);
    dispatch_sync(protectMutableArray, ^{
        [processedImages replaceObjectAtIndex: index withObject: processedImage];
    });
});
```

When `dispatch_apply` returns, `processedImages` will contain all the processed images with their order preserved, but the processing will have been done in parallel. Also note here that the `dispatch_sync` to the serial queue is just to serialize mutations of `processedImages` and has nothing to do with the ordering.